# Why is setWidth/Height not working on EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

In the code below setting width and height directly on nameEdit does not work, I have to use setLayoutParams. Why does not setWidth/Height work? This led to a lot of frustration for me before I found the solution.

```
    EditText nameEdit = new EditText(  theActivity );
    nameEdit.setX(300);
    nameEdit.setY(400);
//      nameEdit.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
//      nameEdit.getLayoutParams().height = 60;

    //final EditText edittext = new EditText(this);
    nameEdit.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    //return edittext;

//      nameEdit.setWidth(100);
//      nameEdit.setHeight(60);
    nameEdit.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    ((ViewGroup) (theActivity).findViewById( android.R.id.content )).addView( nameEdit );
```

Comment: what's wrong with using layoutparams again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why setHeight or setWidth did not work?**

setHeight or setWidth has more to do with the line height of the text than the height of the view.

**Why setLayoutParams works?**

When we set the layout params of the editText, we are telling the parent layout rendering the editText, to set the specified height and width for the view. Therefore, it works fine.

Anyone please feel free to add more details or update my understanding ...

Thanks